# dot in `django-admin.py startproject myproject .`

Tags: django

I keep the question in mind when read through Django source codes for weeks.

Start project with `Django`,

```
django-admin.py startproject myproject . # a tailed dot in the end
```

`manage.py` will be created outside the project folder.

if without '.',

`manage.py` will be included in project folders.

How does the '.' work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The dot means: Create the project directly in the current directory, without creating a folder for it

Comment: Could you introduce the source specification?

Comment: `.` is a shortcut for "current directory". It is not django-specific. It is operating system thing.

Comment: Where can I find the source.Google it return you nothing qualified.

Comment: See here: https://superuser.com/questions/37449/what-are-and-in-a-directory

Comment: What do you mean by the "source"?

Comment: ty, you answered it.

Answer (score 0):

For django 4.1.3 (not sure if there was a difference in earlier versions):

With dot - it creates manage.py outside the project directory, in the current directory from where the command has been executed from.
Without
dot      - it creates manage.py inside the project directory

Comment: When we use `dot` Django admin assumes the current directory is the main directory of the project and creates a folder according to the project name and moves some files in there like settings.py, If I may advise you to improve your answer this is not outside or inside the project, with dot root became here and without dot create new dir and root became that at both status manage.py exist in project dir.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).